# Defining uphill side of roads using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem

I have a big raster of a mountainous region, and I need to extract the uphill side of roads, from the road to the peaks of the mountains.

For a road, I know the uphill side changes to become the downhill side when you make a hairpin turn. For this reason, I believe the processing should start from the lowest road and continue up into the mountains (the highest points).

Is there any possibility of doing this?

I don't have a good knowledge of the Python language.

Comment: Do you have the road network as a separate dataset or just the DEM?

Comment: Yes, I have DEM and the road network as vector file

Comment: What precisely have you tried?

Comment: Do you only care about the road sides or do you also want to know when the road itself is running uphill?